# How to edit stringd in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

i'm new to batch programming but i cant find how to manipulate string in a specific manner like we would do in C++.
i want to create a batch file which would change.

00:1E:90:75:9F:9F

to

001E90759F9F

Comment: `echo %thing::=%` where thing contains `00:1E:90:75:9F:9F`. See `set /?` for help.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: What about using the search function of this site?

Comment: sorry everyone i was not able to find that question but now my batch file works fine thank for helping me out

Answer (score -2):

maybe you can  try this:

```
sed 's/00:1E:90:75:9F:9F/001E90759F9F/' your_file_name
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".